# Criar condição de retorno boolean que verifica se o input está com "focado" ou não com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input

Eu criei uma calculadora, com dois `input`'s: um para cada operando.

O intuito é experimentar uma função switch que deva receber os números caso a `div` que representa o teclado seja clicada, ou apagada o último caracter em caso de clicar na tecla "backSpace" que também está no teclado da calculadora.

Porém, pois o teclado da calculadora só realiza as funcionalidades no primeiro `input`, mesmo com o foco estando no segundo `input`, o cursor volta automaticamente para o primeiro `input` ao ser usado o teclado.

Já tentei usar o método `focus()`, `hasFocus()` entre outras coisas.

```js
const ac=document.querySelector("#id_tecla-AC")
const input1=document.querySelector("#id_aritimetica1")
const input2=document.querySelector("#id_aritimetica2")
const backSpace=document.querySelector("#id_back-Space")
const numbers=[...document.querySelectorAll(".number")]
const sinais=[...document.querySelectorAll(".sinal")]
const igual=document.getElementById("id_symbol-iqual")
const resultado=document.getElementById("id_resultado")
const operacao=document.querySelector("#id_symbol")

numbers.map((element)=>{
    element.addEventListener("click",(event)=>{
        switch(element.textContent){
        case "0" : if(input1.focus()){input1.value+=0}else if(input2.focus()){input2.value+=0}
        break
        case "1" : if(input1.focus){input1.value+=1}else if(input2.focus){input2.value+=1}
        break
        case "2" : if(input1.focus){input1.value+=2}else if(input2.focus){input2.value+=2}
        break
        case "3" : if(input1.focus){input1.value+=3}else if(input2.focus){input2.value+=3}
        break
        case "4" : if(input1.focus){input1.value+=4}else if(input2.focus){input2.value+=4}
        break
        case "5" : if(input1.focus){input1.value+=5}else if(input2.focus){input2.value+=5}
        break
        case "6" : if(input1.focus){input1.value+=6}else if(input2.focus){input2.value+=6}
        break
        case "7" : if(input1.focus){input1.value+=7}else if(input2.focus){input2.value+=7}
        break
        case "8" : if(input1.focus){input1.value+=8}else if(input2.focus){input2.value+=8}
        break
        case "9" : if(input1.focus){input1.value+=9}else if(input2.focus){input2.value+=9}
        break
        case "," : if(input1.focus){input1.value+=","}else if(input2.focus){input2.value+=","}
        break
        default:
        break
       }       
    })
})

backSpace.addEventListener("click",() =>{
   if(input1.value.length){
    input1.value = input1.value.substr(0, input1.value.length -1);
    input1.focus();
    }else if(input2.value.length){
        input2.value = input2.value.substr(0, input2.value.length -1);
        input2.focus();
    }    
})
```

Comment: Algumas dicas: usar `map` para percorrer um array é um uso torto, [leia aqui](/a/426824/112052) para entender melhor. E `focus()` serve para colocar o foco no elemento, não para verificar se ele tem o foco. E `hasFocus` verifica se o documento tem algum elemento com foco, não se o elemento específico está focado. Talvez vc precise definir outra regra para saber quando usar ou outro input. E também dá pra simplificar esse switch, repare que tem muito código repetido (daria pra concatenar o próprio `textContent`, por exemplo, `switch` não parece ser a melhor opção aí)

Comment: Pois é , cara. Fiz algumas buscar em busca de encontrar alguma regra de tratamento para resolver tal problema. Estou ainda em busca, vou dar um repensada uma outa regra. Mas isso isso me deixou encucado, pois é um conhecimento que pode vir a ser muito útil em um projeto. Quanto ao switch é tranquilo, dá para passar tudo em um function e chamar o código apenas uma vez ao evento do click.

Answer (score -3):

Abaixo segue o métodos que criei par fazer a verificação do input que está com FOCO no momento do evento do clique

```js
let condicao=""

input1.addEventListener('focus', () => {
condicao=0
});

input2.addEventListener('focus', () => {
condicao=1
});

backSpace.addEventListener("click",() =>{
    if(condicao==0){
    input1.value = input1.value.substr(0, input1.value.length -1);
    }else if(condicao==1){
    input2.value = input2.value.substr(0, input2.value.length -1);
    }
})
```

Comment: Não precisa dessa variável `condicao`. Em vez disso, use uma variável para guardar o próprio `input` que foi focado. Algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/xvb75smf/

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu estava tentando fazer  ontem, usar o um selector direto para tag `input`, para então pegar o` input` focado. Já o `switch` eu removi todas àquelas linah do códifo e deixei apenas para assim:
 
`for(const element of numbers){
    element.addEventListener("click",(evt)=>{
        verifica(evt.target.textContent)
    })
}`